# How do you restrict what kind of data can be input into a Textbox for Visual Basic?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, textbox

I have created a simple Windows Forms Application through Visual Studio 2013, with two text boxes and a button, which I linked to a database in MySql through MySql connector. What it does is after I input a product id and status number for a product that is found in table A, clicking the button would transfer certain columns for that product's row from table A to table B, and then the original row in table A after the data is transferred would be deleted. This is done by calling a stored procedure from that MySql database that uses the values inputted in the text boxes as parameters. Here's the code for the app below so far.

**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports test_mysql_connection

Public Class Form1
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("Database=****;" & _
            "Data Source=****;" & _
            "User Id=****;Password=****")

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connection.Open()

        cmd.Connection = connection
        cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureC"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_product_id", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@p_product_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_mission_status", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@p_mission_status").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("successfully relocated!")
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        connection.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

**

As the app currently stands though, even though it successfully performs the task I want it to do, I could literally input anything in those boxes, even if they have nothing to do with anything found in table A, and I would still get the message "successfully relocated!" even if nothing from table A is being transferred to table B. I especially don't want to be able to enter the product id and mission number of something from table A that has already been transferred to B and deleted from A. So I'm wondering about how I can restrict what I can input into these text boxes, and perhaps add a few error messages if a product id and mission status that is inputted isn't found on table A. Thanks for any feedback beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is indicated below. Alternatively you could handle the textbox.Validating event and cancel anything that isn't numeric.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    connection.Open()

    if not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) then Msgbox("Must be a number") : return


    cmd.Connection = connection
    cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureC"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_product_id", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters("@p_product_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_mission_status", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters("@p_mission_status").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    if rows <> 0 then
        MessageBox.Show("successfully relocated!") 
    else
        MessageBox.Show("no matching rows.") 
    end if
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: This is really useful! But do you also happen to have  any suggestions for an error message that indicates if a product id that is inputted does not match anything from table A and therefore isn't acceptable?

Comment: See the "no matching rows" part of the code. ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows that we're modified.